# Vim swap delete option not present

Tags: c, vim, swap

My internet connection often fails, causing a Putty disconnect and Vim creating swap files. When I come back and recover, I never get the "(D)elete" option when reopening the file, even if I close the session and restart. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of vim?

Comment: Maybe try http://vi.stackexchange.com! (new site)

Comment: You may want to consider using something like [Mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/), [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), or [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to recover from dropped connections. (They all solve the dropped-connection problem in general, not just for vim.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the vim process is still open that has the same process ID as the old vim session (or the pid got recycled, unlikely). You should see something like `process ID: 37675 (still running)` on one of the lines (seventh line for me), if you do then the delete option won't be there since vim thinks that the owning vim session is still open.

You should kill the other vim session since it still seems to be running. If vim does not detect the something with the process id is open it will offer the delete option and just show, `process ID: 37675`

Another option would be to run inside something like tmux or screen, if you get disconnected you can always reconnect to your old session once you are sshed back into the machine.

Comment: Aah, it appears i wasn't ending the session somehow. Thanks for the answer.